# Seperate pages for mapped items in array using React

Tags: reactjs

This question probably has a very obvious answer but how do you map over a list of say, 40 items in an array and show 10 per page, with numbers at the bottom of the page which represent the 4 different pages of the items in the array.

You click the numbers, for example page 2, and you get the next 10 items in the array.

I am using grid and want to display 10 items per page in 2 rows and 5 columns. Do I have to add each page number at the bottom of the page and create click events on each one to load the next ten elements? I know how to split the array into 4 separate ones with splice.

Seems like surely there would be an easier, automated solution.

Comment: The part of paging which is specific to React is just that you filter an array to only have the elements you want before you pass it to the render function

Comment: @Codebling awesome thanks for that man that makes so much sense. I could pass a different function to the function rendering the items every time a page is clicked. The first function would be on render which is 1-10 and when page 2 is clicked would be onclick event with the next ten, right?

Comment: Maybe the logic that controls the page should be a separate that wraps your component. Whether you do that or not, your items are in state and so is the page number (defaulting to page one). Onclick can just change the page number. And then everything else is like you said